# Flash plugin that allows users to create a PDF or image file

Tags: c#, flash

I am developing a ASP.NET web site where users will need to be able to create their own business cards. So, I'm looking for a tool (most likely Flash) that I can easily integrate into a web site and lets users add text and custom images to their cards and then create an image and/or PDF from their work.

is there a plugin that does this?

Comment: I've found one at http://www.developflash.com - this is very similar to what I need but very expensive (2500 USD). Are there other alternatives out there?

Comment: You might want to clarify exactly what you need if you haven't got an answer yet. If the answers aren't sufficient, tell us why. Otherwise it's more difficult to help.

Comment: OK, I will do that. The example at developflash.com is very close to what I need. It lets users create their own design, with multiple lines of text and outputs to an image file (bmp, jpg, etc). The primary factor is cost - $2500 is outrageous, surely there must be other, cheaper, solutions out there and that's the crux of my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own business-card creator in flash, you can save the view to PDF files using [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this: http://www.shirtnetwork.com/en

It is less of a plugin and much more of a fully customizable software solution, with an administration backend, PDF export, billing etc. . I worked on the client and I must say it is a very mature and potent software and probably can do about anything you want, when it comes to customizing products. I don't know, whether you like the pricing model, OTOH to my knowledge, they also provide provision-free licences.

I don't know, whether there are reasonbly expensive components available, that do this for you, because you can get a load of money out of this business, so I wouldn't expect anyone to give them away for free.

greetz
back2dos